# ImportError: cannot import name 'url_encode' from 'werkzeug'

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am currently running a conda environment with `flask-wtf version 0.14.2` and `wtforms version 2.21` and I have trouble solving this `ImportError: cannot import name 'url_encode' from 'werkzeug'`

The following code is the complete traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
        from flaskblog import app
      File "/Users/justinding/Desktop/test/test_wesite/flaskblog/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
        from flaskblog import routes
      File "/Users/justinding/Desktop/test/test_wesite/flaskblog/routes.py", line 4, in <module>
        from flaskblog.forms import RegistrationForm,LoginForm
      File "/Users/justinding/Desktop/test/test_wesite/flaskblog/forms.py", line 1, in <module>
        from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
      File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/smartbox/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_wtf/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
        from .recaptcha import *
      File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/smartbox/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_wtf/recaptcha/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from .fields import *
      File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/smartbox/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_wtf/recaptcha/fields.py", line 3, in <module>
        from . import widgets
      File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/smartbox/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_wtf/recaptcha/widgets.py", line 5, in <module>
        from werkzeug import url_encode
    ImportError: cannot import name 'url_encode' from 'werkzeug' (/opt/anaconda3/envs/smartbox/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Setting werkzeug==0.16.1 in your requirements file fixes it. The issue is with the 1.0.0 version

Comment: Do we know when there will be a fix included in a 1.x.x version?

Comment: It's probably better to just [set flask-wtf to be 0.14.3](https://github.com/scoringengine/scoringengine/issues/670).

Answer (score 16):

guess the error is related to the new version of werkzeug.
in new werkzeug version there is no "url_encode'.
so try to install an older version of werkzeug
like this : "pip install werkzeug==0.16.0"
mine fixed with this solution

Answer (score 12):

try to import this from werkzeug.urls

Comment: I hardcoded the imports as @zo0m suggested and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Use Below syntax

from werkzeug.urls import url_encode

Answer (score 1):

in our case, we needed werkzeug for flask 2.0.0+:

```
            if flask_version.startswith("2."):
                if python == "3.7":
                    session.install("werkzeug==2.2.3")
                else:
                    session.install("werkzeug==2.3.7")
```

after version 3 (for now) flask appears to install with the appropriate werkzeug version automatically.

Answer (score 0):

url_decode and several other functions are available only until Werkzeug 2.3.6. So this is the version that solve the problem!

Comment: thank you vey much 
this solved an issue where nothing worked
i tried using 0.16 version as suggested by many but it ddidn't work for me
the amazing thing is that i had this error only in the virutal envirornmen and only in one project.. 
if i do the same project outside the virutal enviornment it runs..!!!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade `Werkzeug` and `Flask-WTF` to latest version.

e.g.,

```py
Werkzeug==3.0.0
Flask-WTF==1.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error:

```
from werkzeug.urls import url_encode
ImportError: cannot import name 'url_encode' from 'werkzeug.urls'
```

This error is not always due to werkzeug version. I was getting this error and if I update the version still I was getting errors.

```
pip install Werkzeug --upgrade
```

**Solution:**
This issue is very random and below are exact steps which resolved my issue:

```
pip install werkzeug==0.16.0
pip install Werkzeug --upgrade
pip install -U Flask-WTF
```

After installing 0.16.0 version run the file you will get new error then again upgrade the Werkzeug and Flask-WTF : See if that resolves issue in your case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, upgrading from odoo v13 to odoo v16, i had to replace:

```py
werkzeug.url_encode(post)
```

by:

```py
werkzeug.urls.url_encode(post)
```